# Is it faster to create a new class inside a function or pass it as a parameter in PHP

Tags: php, performance, oop

I've got a class that is used in a few functions independently from one another. So my question is: is it faster to pass the initiated class as a parameter to the function or to create a new instance every time the function is called upon?

Like this:

```
$class_a = new Class_a;

function rnd_fun($class_a){
... do stuff...
}
```

Or like this:

```
function rnd_fun(){
$class_a = new Class_a;
... do stuff...
unset($class_a);
}
```

Comment: This is something you can easily test.

Comment: run a benchmark and see

Comment: I will try that

Comment: Copy and paste code quickly becomes difficult to maintain.  Best to only have the class defined in one place.

Comment: not that much if you've got a decent text editor that allows you to replace strings

Comment: If you remember to do so.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: yeah that's a good piece of advice but still I wanted to be sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to do a benchmark and these are the results by using this 
very creative class

```
class Class_a {
    public $first_name = "";
    public $age = "";

    public function setVar($first_name, $age){
        $this->first_name = $first_name;
        $this->age = $age;
    }

    public function wasteTime(){
        $i = 0;
        while($i < 100){
            $this->age = $this->age * $i;
            $this->age = $this->age / pi();
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

By passing the class as a parameter I got something around 0.46s using this code:

```
$class_a = new Class_a;

$i = 0;
while($i < 10000){
    test($class_a);
    $i++;
}

function test($class_a){
        $class_a->setVar("Geronimo", "72.1");
        $class_a->wasteTime();
    }
```

This is by initiating a new class inside the function:

```
$i = 0;
while($i < 10000){
    test();
    $i++;
}

function test(){
    $class_a = new Class_a;
    $class_a->setVar("Geronimo", "72.1");
    $class_a->wasteTime();
    unset($class_a);
}
```

I have to point out though that the second method took a slightly higher time to execute (around 0.47s).

However I believe that the difference between the two is negligible since both run at around the same speed for this many iteration and their delay won't be noticeable in an average piece of code.